# How to get all (loop throught) checked items from my ListBox ( as object from DB) WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I'm working on WPF application, and I have users, and ofcourse users has some kind of roles, in my case SUPERADMIN AND ADMIN, that roles are stored in table "`Roles`", 
One user could have 1 or more roles, so that means one or more checkbox can be selected on my form (from ListBox).

What I'm supposed to do here : GetALLRoles from Database so I could later add them for certain user and I did it on this way:

```
try
{
    var activeRoles = RolesController.SelectAll();

    if (activeRoles.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(Role r in activeRoles)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(r);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

`listBox` is my ListBox which is used to show Roles from DB

XAML that is showing that:

```
<ListBox  Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,5,0"  Name="listBox" FontSize="15" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In db right now I got 2 roles and when I run app, it is shown on UI (marked with green rectangle):

[image]

But I am wondering now, If I want to save roles for some user, that means I need to select role which I want to save, and I did it

[image]
But when I want to loop to check selected roles I'm having issue:

```
foreach (var item in listBox.SelectedItems)
{
    //Do something...           
}
```

`listBox` is allways Count:0 and I've found that I need to select whole "row" to get selectedItems work, only selecting checkbox is not working acctually :/

How come this is happening and how could I fix this guys?

Comment: @mm8 here it is my friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an boolean property to the Role class that you bind the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` to:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Title}" />
```

You could then determine which roles that are selected using this property:

```
foreach (var role in listBox.Items.OfType<Role>())
{
    if(role.IsChecked)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```